# trying to find unique values using R

Tags: r

I've searched the forums and couldn't quite find anything that would work for me. I've got a kinda unique dataset here where I've recorded what I've done with every hour of my day, and I just want to find all the unique entries for right now. For instance, there are 'sleep' entries, 'homework', 'dinner', all across a hundred or so days, and I just want to find all the possible things I've done then, all the unique entries.

I've tried unique(data), which doesn't get me anywhere, and I've tried unique(data[, 1]). If I write a 'for' loop to do that, how can I merge the list, and further pare their uniqueness down?

```
> data[, 1]
 [1] morning prep  work          work          work          work         
 [6] work          work          work          work          homework     
[11] MNT           chat with Dan dinner        movie         movie        
[16] sleep         sleep         sleep         sleep         sleep        
[21] sleep         sleep         sleep         sleep                      
Levels:  chat with Dan dinner homework MNT morning prep movie sleep work
```

And its class is a 'factor'. Unique pares it down nicely, but then how do I combine all the days into a long character vector that I can use to do my analysis, such as...

```
sum(data=='sleep')
```

But with my list I'll be able to write another 'for' loop and sum everything easily...

Comment: Please show how your data looks. 'unique' should be fine, the only problem can be with data format... try unique(data$action) or whatever you have...

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you're just looking for the `table` function. Pulls out your "unique" factors and counts the frequency in one go:

```
myHomework <- data.frame(StuffIDid = c("morning prep", "work", "work", "work", 
                                       "work", "work", "work", "work", "work", 
                                       "homework", "MNT", "chat with Dan", 
                                       "dinner", "movie", "movie", "sleep", 
                                       "sleep", "sleep", "sleep", "sleep", 
                                       "sleep", "sleep", "sleep", "sleep"))
str(myHomework)
# 'data.frame':    24 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ StuffIDid: Factor w/ 8 levels "chat with Dan",..: 5 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 3 ...
table(myHomework[, "StuffIDid"])
# 
# chat with Dan        dinner      homework           MNT  morning prep         movie 
#             1             1             1             1             1             2 
#         sleep          work 
#             9             8
```

Or, as a `data.frame`:

```
data.frame(table(myHomework[, "StuffIDid"]))
#            Var1 Freq
# 1 chat with Dan    1
# 2        dinner    1
# 3      homework    1
# 4           MNT    1
# 5  morning prep    1
# 6         movie    2
# 7         sleep    9
# 8          work    8
```